# How to make a countdown timer from a specific date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodes

In ReactJS, I need to make a countdown timer from "09/19/2020" and have it all displayed on my page
What this timer considered month, days, hours, etc.
For this timer to count the month, days, hours, etc. from a certain point in time. Not BEFORE any date, but FROM a certain date. Available from "09/19/2020"

My code:

```
import React from "react";

const Timer = () => {
}

export default Timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function calcDiffInMinutes(dateA, dateB) {
  return Math.floor(((dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime()) / 1000) % 60); // TODO CALCULATIONS HERE
}

export default ({ dateFrom }) => {
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [minutesDiff, setMinutesDiff] = useState(
    calcDiffInMinutes(currentDate, dateFrom)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentDate(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [currentDate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMinutesDiff(calcDiffInMinutes(currentDate, dateFrom));
  }, [currentDate, dateFrom]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Date From: {dateFrom.toISOString()}</div>
      <div>CountDown value: {minutesDiff}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Put this in a separate component file called e.g. `CountdownTimer`.
And then you can use it in your app.

See the full example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vmqvy?file=/CountdownTimer.js

P.S. `calcDiffInMinutes` should be done by you to calculate real diff in minutes. You'll also need to create such functions for days/months etc. Or change to single function that returns an object with all the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the past datetime to unix time and subtract that from the current datetime in unix time, and then convert the difference back to whatever display of time you want. Do this every second to obtain a timer.

You could also use a library like `moment.js`, which has a `.unix()` function to convert easily.

Comment: I started learning JS just a week ago, so can I have an example?